# Android isn't playing a YouTube video at the given startSeconds

Tags: android, kotlin, video, youtube

I have embedded a YouTube video into an activity within Android. I am using [this library](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player) to do it. The video loads fine but the issue is that it sometimes it doesn't load at the right seconds

When I call `loadVideo(videoId, 100f)` it should load the video at the 100th second (or 1:40) and sometimes the video does it fine, other times it would load at 0:00 which is not what I want. I want the video to simply start at 1:40.

Another issue this causes is that once I rotate the screen, `onCreate()` is called again, and I am retrieving the `currentSeconds` from the YouTube player, so that the video can resume playing from where it left off. Again I have the same problem, sometimes the video behaves correctly by resuming to the current seconds, or it starts again from 0:00.

I've tried calling `loadVideo()` within onResume and I couldn't get that working. I have a suspicion that perhaps it has something to do with lifecycles. Maybe the video loads either too slow or too fast, I don't know.

I think something wrong is happening here within this function:

```
youTubePlayerView.addYouTubePlayerListener(object : AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
            override fun onReady(youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer) {
                youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId, startSeconds)
                youTubePlayerView.enableBackgroundPlayback(true)
                youTubePlayer.addListener(tracker)
            }
        })
```

Here's my activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), LifecycleObserver {

    private lateinit var youTubePlayerView: YouTubePlayerView
    private lateinit var observer: YouTubeObserver
    private lateinit var tracker: YouTubePlayerTracker
    private var startSeconds: Float = 100f
    private val videoId = "gVGRIBWy6ig"

    // Keys
    private val KEY_CURRENT_SECONDS = "KEY_CURRENT_SECONDS"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        Timber.i("onCreate called")

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            startSeconds = savedInstanceState.getFloat(KEY_CURRENT_SECONDS)
        }

        youTubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youTubePlayerView)
        observer = YouTubeObserver(this.lifecycle, youTubePlayerView)
        tracker = YouTubePlayerTracker()

        youTubePlayerView.addYouTubePlayerListener(object : AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
            override fun onReady(youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer) {
                youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId, startSeconds)
                youTubePlayerView.enableBackgroundPlayback(true)
                youTubePlayer.addListener(tracker)
            }
        })
        Timber.i(tracker.currentSecond.toString())
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState.putFloat(KEY_CURRENT_SECONDS, tracker.currentSecond)
        Timber.i("onSave called")

    }
}
```

Comment: Change videoId to "dQw4w9WgXcQ" and it should work.